# How does array.length-- work?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, arrays

I'm having trouble understanding why people call

```
array.length--
```

after deleting an element in an array (as seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49051856/is-there-a-pop-functionality-for-solidity-arrays) and many others). Why is there need for doing so? When is the length of an array evaluated? Or maybe I'm missing something obvious, what does `array.length--` actually do?

Comment: It's the equivalent of popping the most recent item out of the array (which in that sense serves as a LIFO queue, or a stack if you will).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `array.length--` in order to accurately persist the length of the array.

The confusion comes from the fact that `delete` in Solidity does not actually delete an element from an array, but rather it just sets the element to it's default value (`0` for a `uint256`, for example).

Observe the following code as an example:

```
uint256[] public testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

// testArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
// testArray.length = 5

delete testArray[4];

// testArray = [1,2,3,4,0]
// testArray.length = 5

testArray.length--

// testArray = [1,2,3,4]
// testArray.length = 4
```